# Filter data in DataGrid

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

How would i filter data in one of my data grids, in example:

I have a mysql class:

```
Public Function getArtikli() As DataTable
    Dim query As String = "select id,named,group,art,vpc,mpc,currency,foot,pc from demo.artikli"
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(konekcija)
        Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection)

            adapter.Fill(table)
            Return table
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

This is a function from mainwindow.vb

```
Private Function fillGrids()
    gornjiGrid.ItemsSource = mysql.getArtikli().DefaultView
    gornjiGrid.Items.Refresh()
End Function
```

And i would like to filter returned rows in a grid named "gornjiGrid" using textchanged event for this following textbox:

```
Private Sub textBox1_Copy1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles textBox1_Copy1.TextChanged
    'mysql.getArtikli().DefaultView.RowFilter = " name like '*" & textBox1_Copy1.Text & "*'"
End Sub
```

And finaly this is my datagrid xml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding gornjiGrid}" x:Name="gornjiGrid"  Margin="376,141,15,0" FontSize="12" Height="126" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am strongly recommending you to use MVVM pattern for WPF applications.
Use `ListCollectionView` for `DataGrid.ItemsSource` and `ObservableCollection(Of ...)` for ListCollectionView's Items. Then you use `ListCollectionView.Filter` predicate to filter items in DataGrid. You will be very disappointed and angry with your current oldschool Windows Forms method.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the `DataView` in memory. Also make sure that you spell the column name(s) correctly. There seems to be no "name" column returned from your query but there is a "named" column.

Try this:

```
Private Sub textBox1_Copy1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles textBox1_Copy1.TextChanged
    Dim dataView = CType(gornjiGrid.ItemsSource, System.Data.DataView)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1_Copy1.Text) Then
        dataView.RowFilter = Nothing
    Else
        dataView.RowFilter = " named like '*" & textBox1_Copy1.Text & "*'"
    End If

End Sub
```